# How can I set up an Azure DevOps pipeline in order to be triggered when I push to a BitBucket repository?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, bitbucket, azure-pipelines, devops

I have a BitBucket repository that so far looks like this:

- master
- develop
- feature/a
- feature/b
- feature/c

I'working with Xamarin in order to create an Android/iOS application, so far my pipeline looks like this:

```
# Branches that should trigger the CI pipeline upon change
trigger:
- master
- develop
- feature/*

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  outputDirectory: '$(build.binariesDirectory)/$(buildConfiguration)'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'

- task: SonarCloudPrepare@1
  inputs:
    SonarCloud: 'Sonar Cloud'
    organization: 'org-name'
    scannerMode: 'MSBuild'
    projectKey: 'project-key'
    projectName: 'Project Name'

- task: XamarinAndroid@1
  inputs:
    projectFile: '**/*droid*.csproj'
    outputDirectory: '$(outputDirectory)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: XamariniOS@2
  inputs:
    solutionFile: '**/*.sln'
    configuration: 'Release'
    clean: true
    packageApp: true
    buildForSimulator: true
    runNugetRestore: false

- task: SonarCloudAnalyze@1
- task: SonarCloudPublish@1
  inputs:
    pollingTimeoutSec: '300'
```

But even after I push to a remote **feature/*** branch, or after I merge a PR do **develop**, my build pipeline doesn't run. I've tried to go on the **Triggers** tab, within Azure DevOps and check "**Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here**", then on "**Branch filters**" I include the same branches.

[image]

Here's how the pipeline is connected to my Bitbucket repository.

[image]

However the pipeline still doesn't run unless I do it manually. Any ideas on what am I doing wrong? Shouldn't this work as it is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSTS\Azure-DevOps: Enabling Continuous Integration on pipeline with source from Bitbucket fails with error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53596735/vsts-azure-devops-enabling-continuous-integration-on-pipeline-with-source-from)

Comment: @Nouman Thank you, but no. I'm able to save the changes to the pipeline and I've just verified that Azure DevOps was able to create the necessary web hooks within Bitbucket.

Comment: TBH, your pipeline looks fine. I've recreated a build pipeline using your yml (removed the Sonar Step) and can easily trigger this when I check into a feature branch in BitBucket.

Comment: The issue could be reproduced, when the `develop` branch was set as the "Default branch for manual and scheduled builds", only those branches created from `develop` in Bitbucket repo can trigger the CI build in Azure DevOps, the same for `feature/*`. I think this is the reason we met the issue, but i found this via muliple tests and didn't find any official doc could support so it might be incorrect. And this theory does not apply to `master` for unknown reason.[The theory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx4up.png).